# Winform clone DataGridViewRow along with DataBoundItem

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of pocos like this:

```
List<A> alist;
public class A {
    public string M { get; set; }
    public string N { get; set; }
    public Bs List<B> { get; set; }
}
public class B { 
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

I can bind this to a `dataGridView dgv` no problem.
Now I want to clone a row, along with a copy of `A` in that row.

```
var row = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow;
var alist= (List<A>)((BindingSource)dgv.DataSource).DataSource;
var a = (A)row.DataBoundItem; 
var clone = (DataGridViewRow)row.Clone(); //only copied a blank row, no content
dgv.Rows.Add(clone);
var copya = (A)clone.DataBoundItem; 
as.Add(copya); // This 'copya' is NULL, because dataBoudItem is not copied.
```

How do I make that happen so that clone row has clone data?

I prefer a simpe work around, not going into NotifyPropertyChanged, BindingList and all that if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new "row" in the data instead for binded DataGridView.

```
var currentCell = dgv.CurrentCell;
var bs = (BindingSource)dgv.DataSource;
var data = (List<A>)bs.DataSource;
var currentSelection = (A)row.DataBoundItem;
data.Add(currentSelection);

bs.ResetBindings(false); // This should refresh the grid
dgv.CurrentCell = currentCell; // Put back the current cell
```

Comment: Got my head around it, it works, thanks. just by the way last line dgv.CurrentCell = currentCell will hit exception saying "currentCell doesn't belong to dgv' because binding has been reset. Easy fix to remember colindex and rowindex instead of cell reference.